# Remove validation from customer registration form in magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

I have two registration forms, one for customer and the other for tradeuser. I need to change fields in tradeuser registration form. After submitting this form, getting an error like `"Last Name" is a required value."`. But there is no such field in my form.

I am attaching a screenshot of my page. Please help me to find out a solution.
[image]

**EDIT:** 
This form has a Last Name field. But it's id is `owner_last_name`

Comment: There is a lastname field in your form (Screenshot)

Comment: @Ajith it's id is different, only label is `Last name`

Comment: @geeths But `owner_last_name` is mandatory, so that may be the error you are getting. If it is a custom field can you try changing its validation rule and retry

Comment: @Ajith of course it's a mandatory field, but I filled all the mandatory field before submit.